# Updating the Y position aswell as the X position of the 2D camera

Tags: c#, methods, xna, camera, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2D camera that follows my player around both vertically and horizontally. The camera is only following my player horizontally atm. Ive been told to update the Y part aswell as the X part in my `ScrollCamera()` method, but I couldnt figure out how to do it (ended up making a big mess).

Heres the code:

```
private void ScrollCamera(Viewport viewport)
        {
#if ZUNE
const float ViewMargin = 0.45f;
#else
            const float ViewMargin = 0.5f;
#endif

            // Calculate the edges of the screen.
            float marginWidth = viewport.Width * ViewMargin;
            float marginLeft = cameraPosition + marginWidth;
            float marginRight = cameraPosition + viewport.Width - marginWidth;



            // Calculate how far to scroll when the player is near the edges of the screen.
            float cameraMovement = 0.0f;
            if (Player.Position.X < marginLeft)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginLeft;
            else if (Player.Position.X > marginRight)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginRight;

            // Update the camera position, but prevent scrolling off the ends of the level.
            float maxCameraPositionWidth = Tile.Width * Width - viewport.Width;
            cameraPosition = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPosition + cameraMovement, 0.0f, maxCameraPositionWidth);


        }
```

This is the draw method in my level class:

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            for (int i = 0; i <= EntityLayer; ++i)
                layers[i].Draw(spriteBatch, cameraPosition);
            spriteBatch.End();

            ScrollCamera(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
            Matrix cameraTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-cameraPosition, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default,
                RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null, cameraTransform);

            DrawTiles(spriteBatch);

            Player.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);

            foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
                enemy.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            for (int i = EntityLayer + 1; i < layers.Length; ++i)
                layers[i].Draw(spriteBatch, cameraPosition);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

I'm pretty new to Xna and C# and Im doing this just for fun, but it would be great if someone could tell me how to do it :)

I have tried:

```
private void ScrollCamera(Viewport viewport)
        {
#if ZUNE
const float ViewMargin = 0.45f;
#else
            const float ViewMargin = 0.5f;
            const float ViewHeight = 0.3f;
#endif

            // Calculate the edges of the screen.
            float marginHeight = viewport.Height * ViewHeight;
            float marginTop = cameraPosition + marginHeight;
            float marginBottom = cameraPosition + marginHeight;

            float marginWidth = viewport.Width * ViewMargin;
            float marginLeft = cameraPosition + marginWidth;
            float marginRight = cameraPosition + viewport.Width - marginWidth;


            // Calculate how far to scroll when the player is near the edges of the screen.
            float cameraMovement = 0.0f;
            if (Player.Position.X < marginLeft)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginLeft;
            else if (Player.Position.X > marginRight)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginRight;

            if (Player.Position.Y < marginTop)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.Y - marginTop;
            else if (Player.Position.Y > marginBottom)
                cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginBottom;



            // Update the camera position, but prevent scrolling off the ends of the level.
            float maxCameraPositionWidth = Tile.Width * Width - viewport.Width;
            cameraPosition = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPosition + cameraMovement, 0.0f, maxCameraPositionWidth);

        }
```

Which was not right at all.

Comment: Any chance you could tell us, in more detail, what you've already tried?  Might keep us from making the same mistake twice.

Comment: yeah sure, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you provided I conclude 'cameraPosition' is a float with which you only keep track of the X position. I would recommend using a Vector2 for this. This is technically two floats in one; one for the X position and one for Y. If you do this, you will have to repeat your calculation for the Y value. If you prefer not to use a Vector2, you could make a second variable for the Y position instead.

I am unable to see what you do with the cameraPosition, so I cannot help you with that part for Y.

**Edit**
The draw function you have made is not right, because you have only one variable for the camera position. You will need a variable for the X position, and a second one for the Y position. As I stated above, the typical way to do this in XNA, is via the Vector2 structure. If you are not familiar with structures(or classes), I recommend reading up about it as soon as possible, because they are very important in object oriented programming. A link to the microsoft Vector2 documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx

What you would basically do is take the calculation you had at first.

```
float cameraMovement = 0.0f;
if (Player.Position.X < marginLeft)
    cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginLeft;
else if (Player.Position.X > marginRight)
    cameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginRight;

// Update the camera position, but prevent scrolling off the ends of the level.
float maxCameraPositionWidth = Tile.Width * Width - viewport.Width;
cameraPosition = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPosition + cameraMovement, 0.0f, maxCameraPositionWidth);
```

This is the calculation for the X position of your camera. Your code using Vector2 would be:

```
// Declare a Vector2 cameraPosition where you are now declaring a float cameraPosition right now.

Vector2 cameraMovement = new Vector2(0,0);
if (Player.Position.X < marginLeft)
    cameraMovement.X = Player.Position.X - marginLeft;
else if (Player.Position.X > marginRight)
    cameraMovement.X = Player.Position.X - marginRight;

float maxCameraPositionWidth = Tile.Width * Width - viewport.Width;
cameraPosition.X = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPosition.X + cameraMovement.X, 0.0f, maxCameraPositionWidth);
```

You will have to do similar calculations for cameraMovement.Y and cameraPosition.Y.

When you have these, the only thing you will have to change in your draw function is the Y translation. Currently you have:

```
Matrix cameraTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-cameraPosition, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

As you see, you are only translating in the X axis. After adding the Y axis it looks like this:

```
Matrix cameraTransform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-cameraPosition.X, -cameraPosition.Y, 0.0f);
```

I hope you figure it out now. Good luck!

Comment: And by repeat I mean using marginHeight, marginTop, marginBottom, viewport.Height, Player.Position.Y, etc.

Comment: cameraPosition is a float. I can add give you the draw method aswell so you can see what I do with the cameraPosition?

Comment: If you need any further help, I would need the draw function, yes. I see you have added them already, let's have a look.